# Unable to store archive in s3 bucket

Tags: stellar-core

I need to store archive in aws s3 bucket. My Node configuration is:

```
LOG_FILE_PATH="/home/ubuntu/04.04.2019/Node1/my-core/logs"
BUCKET_DIR_PATH="/home/ubuntu/04.04.2019/Node1/my-core/buckets"
HTTP_PORT=11626
PUBLIC_HTTP_PORT=false
RUN_STANDALONE=false
NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="NodeSyncNetwork"
NODE_SEED="SD4SIIOC4FSOZFWWZN55IR36SSNORD6O7QEYYVMOTX4OWBLRNHT5QDW6 self"
NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=true
PEER_PORT=11625
DATABASE="postgresql://dbname=democore1 user=core1 password=admin host=localhost"
KNOWN_PEERS=["127.0.0.1:11627"]
#COMMANDS=["ll?level=debug"]
CATCHUP_COMPLETE=true
FAILURE_SAFETY=0
UNSAFE_QUORUM=true
[QUORUM_SET]
THRESHOLD_PERCENT=100
VALIDATORS=["$self","GBQHDMQVYOAAPMHFYFVZZBNKD2SL5V23PUQ65TAPQEM4WNRSDNUYEYZS"]
[HISTORY.node1]
get="aws s3 cp  http://s3.amazonaws.com/mynodebuck/node1/{0} {1}"
put=" aws s3 cp {0} http://s3.amazonaws.com/mynodebuck/node1/{1}"
```

After running --newhist command I'm getting this error:

```
2019-04-08T06:15:34.803 GAR4Z [Work WARNING] Reached retry limit 5 for put-remote-file history/00/00/00/history-00000000.json
2019-04-08T06:15:34.803 GAR4Z [Work WARNING] Reached retry limit 5 for put-history-archive-state
2019-04-08T06:15:34.803 GAR4Z [Work WARNING] WorkManager got FAILURE_RAISE from put-history-archive-state
2019-04-08T06:15:34.803 GAR4Z [History FATAL] Failed to initialize history archive 'node1' [HistoryArchiveManager.cpp:200]
2019-04-08T06:15:34.803 GAR4Z [default INFO] Application destructing
2019-04-08T06:15:34.803 GAR4Z [default INFO] Application destroyed
```

Comment: i wonder if you are using this config, as your config specifies `level=debug` but it seems your output log looks like `level=warning`. Could you retry with `--c /home/XXXX/XXXX/your-stellar-core.cfg`? Also, check if `s3.amazonaws.com/mynodebuck` is reachable from your machine.

Answer (score 2):

The `aws s3` command takes `s3://`-scheme URLs. If you give it an `http://`-scheme URL it will get very confused (it looks like it actually loads that URL and then tries to use its contents as an `s3://` URL -- definitely wrong)

Try making these your get and put commands:

```
get="aws s3 cp s3://mynodebuck/node1/{0} {1}"
put="aws s3 cp {0} s3://mynodebuck/node1/{1}"
```